# Override @Observes qualifiers in subclass

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi, observable, qualifiers

I've bean that observes events for some class.

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {
    public void process(@Observes Node) {
        // some logic
    }
}
```

Now I want to create subclass, that will catch only `Node` events with qualifier.

```
@Stateless
public class MySubBean extends MyBean {
    @Override
    public void process(@Observes @MyQualifier Node) {
        // some logic
    }
}
```

But `MySubBean` still gets all `Node` events, sent without qualifier. Also removing `@Observes` and `@MyQualifier` from `MySubBean` doesn't change anything - method is still called.

According to the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/enterprise/event/Observes.html):

> Observer methods are inherited by bean subclasses.

which is great, but is there any option to override it and observe events with different qualifiers then in super class?

I'm using WildFly 10.1.

Answer (score 0):

You can try CDI specialization if you wish to replace your superclass. This way, only the subclass should ever be considered.

http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#specialize_session_bean

Comment: Yea, I know that, but it's isn't my case. I want to have both classes working, and change type of events received in the subclass.